# How do I query an excel list or table with OLEDB?

Tags: excel, ado.net, oledb

Using the [Excel 2010 OleDb driver](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) and an OleDbConnection I can query and manipulate a worksheets and named ranges in a spreadsheet like so:

```
$cn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection $cnStr;
$cmd = $cn.CreateCommand()

$cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Some Named Range] (" + 
@"
    [Name], [Description], 
    [Type], [Val], 
) VALUES(
    'Justin', 'A Programmer', 
    'Senor Developer', 11
)"@
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

$cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Some WorkSheet$]"
$rdr = $cmd.ExecuteReader();
[PSObject[]] $data = [PSObject[]]@();
while ($rdr.Read()) {
    $row = @{}; 0..($rdr.FieldCount-1) | %{$row[$rdr.GetName($_)] = $rdr[$_]; }
    $data += New-Object PSObject -Property $row;
}
```

However, whats the naming convention for tables, which were refered to as lists in Excel 2003?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply cannot do this with the OleDB or ODBC driver.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the listobject/table's address:

```
Dim Table as Excel.ListObject
dim TableAddress as String

Set Table = Worksheets("Some Worksheet").ListObjects("SomeTable")
TableAddress = Table.Range.Address(RowAbsolute:=False,ColumnAbsolute:=False)
...
$cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Some WorkSheet$" TableAddress & "]"
```

Comment: I want to do this from OleDb, not Excel COM interop. I don't want Excel installed on the server generating this file, just the [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255).

Comment: Right.  Assuming the naming conventions are the same, I don't think you can refer to the table by name, even though you can to a range.  I think you have to use the address.  One additional thing in my answer that's wrong even in Excel, is the address has to be relative, i.e., no dollar signs.